# what happens if I push code to heroku in the middle of a scheduled job?

Tags: heroku

I have a lot of scheduled tasks that update my site every night. What would happen if I was to do a code push while those tasks are running?  Will they be stopped, or will they be allowed to complete (running the old code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scheduled tasks run as [one-off dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos). Those aren't restarted when your app is deployed. Only monitored dynos as (web and worker for example).

So if you deploy your app while the scheduler runs, the task will keep running on the previous release of your app.
The next task will be started on the new release.